# Foreign Key References to Primary Key in the Same Table EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have class in my MVC project and I used Entity Framework 6. Every person has a Master (`master_Id`) and it references to the same table (primary key in Person table). My way does not work... what's the solution?

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int Master_Id { get; set; }
        public  virtual Person Master { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int? MasterId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public virtual Person Master { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. but, in your code, it adds a column named Master_Id1. It's the same error that my code makes...